# Do I really need motor drivers for a quadcopter?

Tags: mosfet, dc-motor, driver, quad-copter

I am planning to build a quadcopter, so I searched about motor drivers, then I thought "Do I really need a motor driver?", I mean the only thing I want to control is the motors' speeds, so won't MOSFET be enough for that?

Comment: Yes, you really do need motor drivers. I recommend you look up just how the kinds of motors used in quadcopters work; they're usually three-phase permanent-magnet AC motors.

Comment: Won't DC motors work?

Comment: For a start, how will you get velocity (RPM) feedback to your control system if you use a simple DC motor?

Comment: I can check the motor's datasheet and control the motor's velocity using MOSFET

Comment: What happens if something blocks the rotor?

Comment: How **precisely** can you control motor speed using just a MOSFET? How precisely do you **need** to control speed in order to maintain stable flight? Do every motor and every MOSFET have exactly the same characteristics?

Comment: "I can check the motor's datasheet and control the motor's velocity using MOSFET " No, you can't, or at least not simply. At the least, RPM will vary with load, Then you have issues like the motor winding resistance changing with temperature (both external and load-produced). You would need to add an external sensor to each motor shaft.

Comment: It all has to do with current or RdsOn ratios. If you had to drive 1kA from 1mA at high dV/dt PWM you might need 3 or 4  cascaded Bridge drivers due to the switching losses and load capacitance increases with the current capacity of a MOS switch

Comment: So can the motors drivers control the velocity and change it according to the temperature and load on the motor and other variables to make the velocity stable?

Comment: Quadcopter motors are not controlled for a desired speed, rather the loop is closed around the behavior of the aircraft.  Small ones using brushed motors do indeed use a single FET per motor PWM'd from the processor.  Spend some time working with an open source firmware reflashed into a 20 gram toy before you think about doing anything fully original or larger.  The wildly ignorant replies you are getting demonstrate why you should pursue experiential knowledge somewhere like rcgroups rather than guesses from first principles here.

Comment: @ChrisStratton so what should I do now?

Comment: Go read the posts on rcgroups written by people who actually do this and know what they are talking about, rather than the chorus of armchair irrelevance here.  Spend a couple of days reading before you post, as you'll likely find your questions have already been covered many times before.

Comment: I'm very new to this field (electronics) so what do you mean by rcgroups?

Comment: r = radio, c = control. Groups of people who radio control things, like quadcopters.

Comment: https://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showthread.php?2876797-Boldclash-bwhoop-B-03-opensource-firmware which is a derivation for a shielded prop aircraft from https://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showthread.php?2512604-Eachine-H8-mini-acro-firmware etc